# How do I make a column not null and be a foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table that is a foreign key of another table and make it not null, but I am running into trouble making both happen. I was able to successfully get foreign keys working that did not require NOT NULL but I can't get both working.

Here is the line giving me trouble

```
CONSTRAINT instructor FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Instructor(id) NOT NULL
```

then I get the error:

```
CONSTRAINT instructor FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Instructor(id) NOT NULL,
                                                                 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Also, I am getting a weird error when trying to create a table (note, this table is created after creating the table that contains the above error) where it fails at a very trivial part:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment (
       CONSTRAINT class_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Class(id) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT member_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES RecCenterMember(id) NOT NULL,
       cost int NOT NULL
);
```

Then for that command I get this error:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment (
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

How can I fix these two errors?

Comment: Your fields need defined before constraints using them. It is also highly unlikely the same field, especially one named id, should reference two other tables. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the column before you try creating constraints on the column.

You have:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment (
       CONSTRAINT class_id  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Class(id) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT member_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES RecCenterMember(id) NOT NULL,
       cost int NOT NULL
);
```

You need:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment (
       id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT class_id REFERENCES Class(id),
       CONSTRAINT member_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES RecCenterMember(id),
       cost INT NOT NULL
);
```

Note that in the first line, the FOREIGN KEY isn't necessary because the column is implied.  In the second line, the `id` is identified.  You could also write:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment
(
       id INT NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT class_id  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Class(id),
       CONSTRAINT member_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES RecCenterMember(id),
       cost INT NOT NULL
);
```

It is unusual, though not automatically wrong, to make a single column (`id`) be a foreign key of two tables simultaneously.  It isn't clear if you actually want three columns in your table — and if you do, which column names are in your table.

You could also use the appropriate notation for an automatically allocated type in MySQL syntax (`SERIAL` instead of `INT NOT NULL`, or add `AUTO_INCREMENT`, etc).

Maybe you're really after:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment
(
       id          SERIAL,
       class_id    INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT class_id  REFERENCES Class(id),
       member_id   INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT member_id REFERENCES RecCenterMember(id),
       cost        INT NOT NULL
);
```

This makes more sense in general.  You're creating a new enrollment record for a pre-existing class, and for a pre-existing recreation centre member, and recording its cost.

---

#### Syntax diagrams vs actual behaviour

If, as [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854890/how-do-i-make-a-column-not-null-and-be-a-foreign-key-in-mysql/32855001?noredirect=1#comment53561153_32855001) — and I've no reason whatsoever to disbelieve him — MySQL recognizes but does not respond to the `REFERENCES` clause in a column definition in a [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) statement but only acts on full `FOREIGN KEY` clauses, then you have to adjust my suggested answers from their syntactically correct but semantically ignored form to something like:

Option 1 (minimally changing the SQL from the question):

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment (
       id INT NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT class_id  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Class(id),
       CONSTRAINT member_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES RecCenterMember(id),
       cost int NOT NULL
);
```

Option 2 (what I consider the most plausible version):

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment
(
       id          SERIAL,
       class_id    INT NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT  fk_class_id  FOREIGN KEY (class_id)  REFERENCES Class(id),
       member_id   INT NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT  fk_member_id FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES RecCenterMember(id),
       cost        INT NOT NULL
);
```

Or some other variant of this syntax based on the desired table schema ignoring the FK constraints, then adding the constraints along the lines shown.

#### Key Point

You must define the columns before you define the foreign keys based on those columns.

Comment: thanks for the help. Don't get me started on how unusual this all is... this is for a class with a bad professor. When I create the tables and use 'Describe TableName' none of the foreign key columns show up, and I can not insert manually with foreign key collumns. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Well, you'd have to have inserted the appropriate rows in the Class table and the RecCenterMember tables _before_ you can insert in the Enrollment table.  And, if the ID values in Enrollment are auto-generated, then you have to predict what value will be generated in Enrollment so that you can insert the correct values in Class and RecCenterMember — which is kinda tricky if the system is running with multiple users adding stuff at about the same time.  Are you sure you don't need `class_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Class(Id)` and `member_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES RecCenterMember(Id)`?

Comment: Well I am filling a database manually because of the constraints of the homework assignment (literally copying a table in word by hand), and When I try to insert into the table with foreign key like this: INSERT INTO RecCenterMember (f_name, l_name, dob, family_id) VALUES ('Abby', 'Smith', '5/21/1983', (SELECT id FROM FamilyPackage where id=1));                      I get an error saying that family_id is an invalid identifier

Comment: Despite the fact that family_id is in fact the name of the column that I am trying to insert into

Comment: @JonathanLoeffler you're syntactically correct but the answer isn't right.  MySQL [parses but ignores](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) "inline `REFERENCES`" in column definitions.  Foreign keys can only be enforced if defined `[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]` separately from the columns in MySQL.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Ouch!  That is the sort of detail about MySQL that someone who can read syntax diagrams but doesn't use the product would be hard-pressed to guess.  Frankly, that is worse that not recognizing the syntax.  I'd heard of such issues in the past (many years past); I was under the cozy, but now shattered, illusion that most such issues had been resolved.